# Why can't Perl's DBD::DB2 find dbivport.h during installation?

Tags: perl, dbd

We are using a Perl utility to dump data from DB2 database. We installed DBI package and it is asking for DBD package also.

We dont have root access and when we try to install DBD package we are getting the following error:

```
    ERROR BUILDING DB2.pm
    [lijumathew@intblade03 DBD-DB2-1.78]$ make
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lijumathew/lperl/perlsrc/DBD-DB2-1.78/Constants'
    gcc -c  -I"/db2/db2tf1/sqllib/include" -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=pentium4   -DVERSION=\"1.78\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.78\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Constants.c
    Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::DB2::Constants ()
    chmod 644 Constants.bs
    rm -f ../blib/arch/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.so
    gcc  -shared -L/usr/local/lib Constants.o  -o ../blib/arch/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.so
    chmod 755 ../blib/arch/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.so
    cp Constants.bs ../blib/arch/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.bs
    chmod 644 ../blib/arch/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.bs
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lijumathew/lperl/perlsrc/DBD-DB2-1.78/Constants'
    gcc -c  -I"/db2/db2tf1/sqllib/include" -I"/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI" -I"/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI" -I"/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI" -I"/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI"  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=pentium4   -DVERSION=\"1.78\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.78\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   DB2.c
    In file included from DB2.h:22,
                     from DB2.xs:7:
    dbdimp.h:10:22: dbivport.h: No such file or directory
    make: *** [DB2.o] Error 1
```

How do we fix this? Do we need root access to resolve this?

Comment: Which version of DBI do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a problem because most perl modules, including DBD-DB2, aren't written to be installed to different places than the DBI module, which is what happens if you try to install things as non-root.  To get this to work, you need to add a line like this to the Makefile:

```
DEFINE =  -DDB2_CACHE_FIX  -I${DBI_INCL}
```

and set DBI_INCL to the directory that has the DBI header files.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at CPAN forum for [DBD::DB2 make failed](http://cpanforum.com/threads/9760)

Also, if you do below can help you out:

```
Set the DB2 environment variable

   1. In C Shell setenv DB2_HOME $HOME/sqllib
   2. In Bash Shell export DB2_HOME=$HOME/sqllib
```

Install Module:

```
# perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=path
# make
# make test
# make install
```

However, it would be helpful to answer the problem if you can provide us with the perl -V output, the platform you are on and DBI version.